# setting long sql query in bat method

Tags: batch-file

just wondering how to set a bat file to run a long single query.
The sample quote sounds like this -

`create trigger blablabla after update of blablabla
order 2 on blablabla
referencing oldies as olddata newbie as newdata
for each row
begin
  declare blablabla numeric(20);
  if(olddata.blablabla = 1) and(newdata.blablabla = 3) then
    update blablabla set
      blablabla = '2' where 
  end if
end`

possible to place such long single statement to run using bat method ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, which I don't believe I do, you can use the `&&` to separate each command as long as all the commands can be executed successfully. Example:

```
@echo off && cls && echo This is one line && echo This is another line && echo This is the last line && pause >nul && exit
```